# Find google.sheet file that was created in Sheets API using C#

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4

After I created a credential and an initialize service, I created a Spreadsheets using this:

`service.Spreadsheets.Create(myNewSheet).Execute();`

Then, do an update or batch update on the newly created spreadsheet using the SpreadsheetsID such as:

`SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(requestBody, awsomNewSheet.SpreadsheetId, range);`

It was successful and got a response, but i couldn't find the newly created file on my Google Drive.

is there any guide?

Answer (score 1):

It should be created and available in your Google Drive.

But as a workaround, when you use [Spreadsheet.create()](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create?hl=en) it will return a [Spreadsheet Resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet) response body.

**I have 3 options for you:**

1. Get the **file's** **title** in the response body under `properties->title` and search for files with specific title in your Google Drive using this search query:

   `title:<replace with your file title>`
2. Get the **spreadsheetUrl** from the response body and use that to access your file
3. Get the **spreadsheetId** from the response body and use that to access your file using this link:

   `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<replace with spreadsheet id>/edit?`

---

**Sample Response Body using the API Explorer:**

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": "1TNK_uduyRQ82TQQJ13qtLnu58bDZxxxxxx",
  "properties": {
    "title": "Sheet API Test",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "autoRecalc": "ON_CHANGE",
    "timeZone": "Etc/GMT",
    },
    
    .....
    
  "spreadsheetUrl": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TNK_uduyRQ82TQQJ13qtLnu58bDZxxxxxx/edit?ouid=xxxxxx&urlBuilderDomain=example.com"
}
```